# yii2 сессия удаляется при обновлении страницы

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

написал в контроллере

```
    $session1 = Yii::$app->session;
    $session1->set('select', $select);
```

в layout

```
 $session1 = Yii::$app->session;
 $www = $session1->get('select');

var_dump($www);
```

и при обновлении страницы получаю NULL

Comment: сессию сначала надо открыть )

Comment: дело в том что сессия 1 раз сохраняется, но после как обновляешь страницу она исчезает

Comment: тут скорее вопрос в том, что у автора в конфигах.